Are the Euclidean and orthogonal groups locally isomorphic?
I appear to have proven a very counterintuitive result. I would like it if someone could confirm my reasoning.
The Euclidean group $\mathrm{Euc}(n)$ is made up of matrices of the form
$
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}
$
for $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A\in \mathrm{SO}(n).$ Then its Lie algebra is the collection of matrices
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}
$
for $A\in \mathfrak{so}(n)$, with the Lie bracket given by the matrix commutator. On the other hand, the special orthogonal group $\mathrm{SO}(n+1)$ is known to have the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(n+1)$ of skew-symmetric matrices which can be written
$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -v^T\\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}$
for $A\in \mathfrak{so}(n).$ Then
the map $\mathfrak{euc}(n)\to \mathfrak{so(n+1)}$ given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -v^T\\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a Lie algebra isomorphism since the bracket of $
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}
$
with
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\\ w & B
\end{pmatrix}
$ is given by
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\\ Aw-Bv & AB-BA
\end{pmatrix}
$$
while the bracket of
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -v^T\\\ v & A
\end{pmatrix}
$
with
$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -w^T\\\ w & B
\end{pmatrix}
$
is equal to
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -(Aw-Bv)^T\\\ Aw-Bv & AB-BA.
\end{pmatrix}
$$
From the isomorphism of Lie algebras it would follow that there is a local isomorphism between $\mathrm{Euc}(n)$ and $\mathrm{SO}(n+1)$ that fixes their common subgroup $\mathrm{SO}(n).$
Is there a mistake? If not, is there an easy way to write down or describe the local isomorphism (without using the exponential map)?

Check your bracket computations: The special orthogonal group $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1)$, $n > 1$, is semisimple but the Euclidean group is not (what is its radical?), so the groups cannot be isomorphic

@TravisWillse Thanks, I'm really happy to hear this! The possibility of an isomorphism was seriously challenging my intuition about flat vs. spherical geometries.

You're welcome. It's sometimes helpful to think of $\operatorname{Euc}(n)$ (the oriented isometry group of the plane) as sitting between $\operatorname{SO}(n + 1)$ (the oriented isometry group of the sphere) and $\operatorname{SO}(n, 1)$ (the oriented isometry group of hyperbolic space).

Following the comment by Travis Willse, I did make mistake in my bracket computation. The bracket of
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -v^T \\\ v & A
\end{bmatrix}
$
with
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -w^T \\\ w & B
\end{bmatrix}
$
should be
$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -(Aw-Bv)^T \\\ Aw-Bv & AB-BA-vw^T+wv^T
\end{bmatrix}.
$
